# Spring security filter should be called after login in reactive programming

Tags: filter, spring-security, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, custom-authentication

[CustomerWebFilter class] Here in the filter class I need to recheck urls which doesn't need any authentication or authorization. I don't want a filter method call for specified urls like login and others. Filter should be called after successful login only.

[Configuration Security class using ServerHttpSecurity] here I have already placed http.addFilterAfter(customerWebFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION);

P.S. The flow described below is working but I want to improvise it.

```
@Log4j2
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomerWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    private final AccountRoleMenuViewEntityService accountRoleMenuViewEntityService;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();

        final List<String> ALLOWED_ENDPOINTS = Arrays.asList("/assets/", "/bootstrap/", "/plugins/");
        final List<String> ALLOWED_URL = Arrays.asList("/login", "/logout",
                "/forgotpassword", "/sendcode", "/verifycode", "/newpassword", "/razorpay-webhook");

        if (ALLOWED_ENDPOINTS.parallelStream().anyMatch(allowedWords ->
                StringUtils.startsWith(request.getPath().pathWithinApplication().value(), allowedWords))) {
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        }
        if (ALLOWED_URL.parallelStream().anyMatch(allowedWords ->
                StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(request.getPath().pathWithinApplication().value(), allowedWords))) {
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        }

        log.debug("Inside filter request: {} ", request.getPath().pathWithinApplication());
        String allowedPrefix = request.getPath().pathWithinApplication().value();

        if (allowedPrefix != "/" && allowedPrefix.length() > 1) {
            String[] urlComponents = request.getPath().pathWithinApplication().value().split("/");
            allowedPrefix = "/" + urlComponents[1] + "/" + urlComponents[2];
        }
        AtomicReference<String> value = new AtomicReference<>(allowedPrefix);

        return exchange.getPrincipal()
                .flatMap(principal -> {
                    log.debug("principal.getName(): {}", principal.getName());

                    AtomicInteger runCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

                    if (value.get().equalsIgnoreCase("/")) {
                        value.set("/customer/dashboard");
                    }
                    return accountRoleMenuViewEntityService.findByUsername(principal.getName())
                            .flatMap(accountRoleMenuView -> {
                                log.debug("controller: {}", accountRoleMenuView.getController());
                                if (accountRoleMenuView.getController().contains("/")) {
                                    String[] controllerComponents = accountRoleMenuView.getController().split("/");
                                    String controllerPrefix = "/" + controllerComponents[1] + "/" + controllerComponents[2];
                                    log.debug("controllerPrefix: {} value: {}", controllerPrefix, value.get());
                                    if (controllerPrefix.equalsIgnoreCase(value.get())) {
                                        runCount.getAndIncrement();
                                    }
                                }
                                return Mono.just(runCount);
                            }).count()
                            .flatMap(count -> {
                                if (runCount.get() == 0) {
                                    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
                                }
                                return chain.filter(exchange);
                            });
                });
    }
}





    @Configuration
    @EnableWebFluxSecurity
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class ConfigurationSecurity {
    
        private final CustomerWebFilter customerWebFilter;
        private final RememberMeSuccessHandler rememberMeSuccessHandler;
    
        @Bean
        public SecurityWebFilterChain configure(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
            http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/login", "/logout", "/assets/**", "/bootstrap/**", "/plugins/**",
                "/forgotpassword", "/sendcode", "/verifycode", "/newpassword", "/razorpay-webhook").permitAll();
            http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/customer/**").hasRole("CUSTOMER");
            http.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().authenticated();
            http.addFilterAfter(customerWebFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION);
    
            http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .authenticationSuccessHandler(rememberMeSuccessHandler)
                .authenticationFailureHandler(new AuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(new AccessDeniedHandler())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .requiresLogout(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/logout"))
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
            return http.build();
        }
    
        @Bean
        ReactiveAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager(AccountDataService accountDataService) {
            return new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(accountDataService);
        }
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `P.S. The flow in the images is working but I want to improvise it.` what images? and your question doesnt really make sense. permitAll permits you access to the endpoints, why do you need a seperate filter?

Comment: @Toerktumlare Kindly check the updated question. In my case permitAll is not working after adding filter so I explicitly added logic of permitAll in filter method as well. In filter there is a condition which returns forbidden page for unauthorized urls. I want to remove allowed_urls condition check from filter method and make permitAll working.

Comment: Post your security config instead and remove the filter, enable permitAll and then enable debug logs and look at them to find out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a misunderstanding about how filter chain works.

By registering a bean of `SecurityWebFilterChain` you've created a filter chain with a specific `ServerHttpSecurity` object, which applies defined rules for this chain, and these rules are applied *for **every request** by default*, but can be restricted using `securityMatcher(ServerWebExchangeMatcher)` (you can see documentation on this method [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/web/server/ServerHttpSecurity.html#securityMatcher(org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.ServerWebExchangeMatcher))).

And rules, defined after `ServerHttpSecurity.authorizeExchange()` call, are applied after the filter chain, when there is an `Authentication` object in the security context holder, that can be checked on the presence of roles to decide whether it's allowed to reach certain endpoint.

So, if you want different security filter chains for different urls in your application you have 2 options:

1. define multiple `SecurityWebFilterChain` beans: one for paths, where you need authentication and your custom filter, and the other - for paths without authentication and without your custom filter.
   You can see documentation and examples on multiple filter chains support [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/configuration/webflux.html#jc-webflux-multiple-filter-chains), with the `securityMatcher` method usage.
2. create a rule inside a filter to define whether it must be applied.

I think you've already implemented the second approach. Advice on improvement - extract a method like `shouldFilter` and use `ServerWebExchangeMatcher` to combine your two String arrays into one and use the same way to compare exchange path with matcher, including ones with /** wildcard, for example like this:

```
public class CustomerWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    private final String[] ALLOWED_URL = {"/assets/", "/bootstrap/", "/plugins/", "/login", "/logout",
            "/forgotpassword", "/sendcode", "/verifycode", "/newpassword", "/razorpay-webhook"};
    
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return exchangeForFiltering(exchange, chain)
                .flatMap(webExchange -> {

                    // your code here

                    return chain.filter(exchange);
                });
    }

    private Mono<ServerWebExchange> exchangeForFiltering(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return Mono.just(exchange)
                .filterWhen(this::shouldFilter)
                .switchIfEmpty(chain.filter(exchange).then(Mono.empty()));
    }
    
    private Mono<Boolean> shouldFilter(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(ALLOWED_URL))
            .matches(exchange).map(ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult::isMatch);
    }
}
```